# I can't post from org2blog

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I use Emacs 24 and org2blog to publish in my blog.
I have a problem, when I want to publish my buffer, *Emacs* shows:

`xml-rpc-request: Why? url-http-response-status is nil`

????

Comment: Please fix your markup, and be more precise:  Name the command that use to publish the buffer, show the *exact* error message, and the backtrace after `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It worked for me".  I find that the answer is often to pull the latest version of .org.

```
#! /bin/sh -x -u -e
#
# Get latest version of org-mode in ~/src/org-mode
#

mkdir -p ~/src
cd ~/src

# pull for first time if we don't have it

if [ ! -d ~/src/org-mode ]; then
    git clone git://orgmode.org/org-mode.git
else

    # get updates, if any

    cd ~/src/org-mode
    git pull
fi

# build the autoloads
cd ~/src/org-mode
make autoloads

# Add to .emacs, .emacs.d/init.el, whatever...
#
#(add-to-list 'load-path "~/src/org-mode/lisp/")
#(add-to-list 'load-path "~/src/org-mode/contrib/lisp/" t)
```

https://github.com/eludom/HOWTO/blob/master/getLatestOrg.sh